# Inserting Block to Midpoint of (p1,p2) Points & Divide (p1,p2) Distances and Insert Blocks

Tags: vba, autocad

I'm looking for inserting block to the midpoint of two points that I selected (p1,p2). However, I'm having some troubles and it should be simple but it's not working.

In further phase, I want to add a divide section and I want to divide, with d number that I define, equally the [p1,p2] distance and put same blocks over there. But I'm stuck.

If you can help, I'd be so appreciated. Thank you

Here is my code:

```
Sub line()

Dim p1, p2, pTotal(0 To 2), pT(0 To 2) As Variant, b1 As AcadBlockReference

p1 = ThisDrawing.Utility.GetPoint(, "p1")
p2 = ThisDrawing.Utility.GetPoint(, "p2")

For i = 0 To 2
pT(i) = p1(i) + p2(i)
pTotal(i) = pT(i) / 2
Next i

Set b1 = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(pTotal, "BLOCKNAME123", 1#, 1#, 1#, 0#)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return a 3D array from the midpoint of the 2 3D arrays that you pass it.

```
Public Function GetMidPoint(p1, p2) As Variant
    Dim midX As Double: Dim midY As Double: Dim midZ As Double
        
    midX = (p2(0) - p1(0)) / 2 + p1(0)
    midY = (p2(1) - p1(1)) / 2 + p1(1)
    midZ = (p2(2) - p1(2)) / 2 + p1(2)
    
    GetMidPoint = Array(midX, midY, midZ)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Set b1 = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(GetMidPoint(p1, p2), "BLOCKNAME123", 1#, 1#, 1#, 0#)
```

Comment: thanks for you help firstly, on the other hand I'm still having problems. i put p1, p2 getpoints in the function of getmidpoint and in a sub, i put b1 = ...InsertBlock... but I had Invalid Procedure call or Argument error. What should I do?

Comment: You don't put the insert block line inside of the function. Look at my note about usage.